# document.getElementById("app").innerHTML fails when using imports

Tags: javascript, html, css, web

First Js file (testtest.js):

```
let test = "<h1>hello</h1>";
module.exports = test;
```

Second Js file:

```
const test = require('./testtest');
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = "<h1>hello</h1>";
```

When I try use `document.getElementById("app").innerHTML` when I am using import, it fails to show HTML but, if I comment the `import` line it works as expected.

Can you help what is problem solution?

Comment: Did you mean to write document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = test;

Answer (score 0):

This looks like a combination of server side js and client js. Client side js doesn't use `module.exports` or `require`. Ofc you can use a bundler but based on the post I don't think you are.

file: `testtest.js`

```js
let test = "<h1>hello</h1>";
export default test;
```

second js file:

```
//this import must be top level
import test from "./testtest.js";
document.getElementById("app").innerHTML = test;
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/export

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/web/javascript/reference/statements/import

Comment: Using Es6 import export syntax raise a syntax error :

Comment: using es6 syntax import and export default raise a syntax error : PS C:\test> node rendertextindex.js
C:\test\rendertextindex.js:1
import test from "./testtest.js";
^^^^^^

SyntaxError: Cannot use import statement outside a module
?[90m    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:891:18)?[39m
?[90m    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:991:10)?[39m

Comment: make sure to have `type="module"` in your script tags, so `<script type="module"></script>`